# Find a word from DOM by comparing from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to compare my `voice` attribute from array but unable to think how to do that I use `forEach`, `$.inArray` but didn't get any success.

What I need to do is that first I take the `voice` attribute value and compare it with the items of array. Then, if the word matches with one item in the array, I change my CSS.

HTML:

```
<div voice="play">Play</div>
<div voice="test">Pause</div>
<div voice="stop">Stop</div>
```

JS:

```
var word = ['plays', 'play', 'clay', 'lay']
var command = $("[voice]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('voice') == word.forEach()
});
console.log(command);
var attr_array;
if (command.length) {
    attr_array = command.attr('voice');
}
if (attr_array.length) {
    command.css({
        'color': 'red'
    });
} else {
    console.log("command did not match!");
}
```

Simply i want to know how to compare my array with the attribute's value.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: `return word.indexOf($(this).attr('voice')) > -1;`

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a voice attribute in HTML.

Comment: @PHPglue I think you're fully aware that there isn't.  However, if you've got something helpful to say to the OP then please do say it :)

Comment: You can see below my working snippet!

Comment: Thanks @Satpal it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf()` to check if your element's attribute is in `word` or not.

```js
var word = ['plays', 'play', 'test', 'lay']

$("[voice]").filter(function() {
    return  word.indexOf($(this).attr('voice')) > -1
  }).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div voice="play">Play</div>
<div voice="test">Pause</div>
<div voice="stop">Stop</div>
```

However, if you want to do something else when the element's attribute is not in the array `word`, `each()` will be better than `filter`. Filter returns only the elements whose attribute `voice` is in the array `word` whereas `each` will loop over all the elements.

```js
var word = ['plays', 'play', 'test', 'lay']
$("[voice]").each(function() {
    if( word.indexOf($(this).attr('voice')) > -1){
      $(this).css("color","red");
    }
    else{
      //something else
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div voice="play">Play</div>
<div voice="test">Pause</div>
<div voice="stop">Stop</div>
```

Comment: If the voice attribute is found in the array `word`, `indexOf()` will return its index which is superior or equal to 0; if the voice attribute is not found, the index returned is equal to -1. Don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if it helped you @naveendharni :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 :

```
var word = ['plays', 'play', 'clay', 'lay']
var command = $("[voice]").filter(function() {
    return word.includes($(this).attr('voice'));
});
console.log(command);
```

Or you could use Array.indexOf function :

```
    var word = ['plays', 'play', 'clay', 'lay']
    var command = $("[voice]").filter(function() {
        return word.indexOf($(this).attr('voice'))>-1;
    });
    console.log(command);
```